# Prevent many requests initially with SPA

Tags: ajax, http, single-page-application, axios

I am currently developing a web app using vue. When my app starts it makes several requests to my api to get necessary resources.

```
await Promise.all([
    store.dispatch('setUserOnStartup'),
    store.dispatch('getAds'),
    store.dispatch('getCompanies'),
    store.dispatch('getCities')
]);
```

I am just wondering if you usually try to prevent this in your apps? If you make an endpoint where you get all the initial resources at once? For ex: `/api/initial`

Are there any other ways to prevent this or is it fine to do my approach with several requests initially?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) to the rescue.

You can fetch all you need with single request, if all entities you need are related. See http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes for details.